# How do you change text with j query inside of a certain span/id=aaa?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I posted the start of an example, where the country is US
and it needs to be converted to United States 
and the US in TOYS R US can be changed since it matches

https://jsfiddle.net/yy4po40x/

```html
TOYS R US
<span id="aaa">
    <p>
        123 main street
    </p>
    <p>
        US
    </p>
</span>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, other than you want to change some text in your HTML; for that you can use http://api.jquery.com/text

Comment: You're not really using [`<span>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) correctly. Perhaps you meant to use a <div>? I recommend that you learn about all of the HTML elements before you try to use jQuery.

Comment: matches what? what do you want to change to what?

Comment: US and it needs to be converted to United States

Comment: if you want to change the text inside html element then select the element like $("selector").text("yourtext")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
TOYS R US
<span id="aaa">

  <p>
    123 main street
  </p>
  <p>
    US
  </p>

</span>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("#aaa").html(String($("#aaa").html()).replace(/US/g, 'United States'));
});
</script>
```

Working Demo [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/hjrmnpby/)

Comment: Hi SNM, that's what I was getting, look at the top, the TOYS R US has changed too, I can't have that change, only inside of the span, can change

Comment: you didnt mentioned that, anyhow i have updated the code

Comment: great work, (and to others that helped; not hated!)  thanks.

Comment: if the code met your requirement please accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood without understanding the matching thing that you said, if you want to change texts inside paragraphs inside span, then here's your solution using jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#aaa p:nth-child(2)').html('USA'); 
});
```

Whereas, If you want to replace something globally then :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("body").html($('body').html().replace(/US/g, 'United States'));
)};
```

But your html is wrongly coded. This is the right way.

```
<div id="aaa">
    <p>
        123 main street
    </p>
    <p>
        US
    </p>
</div>
```

You don't actually use `span` to enclose `p` tags. `Span` is for selecting a small area basically which do not change any alignment of the webpage but for the purpose of calling some properties to change something inside it.

The right way to use `span` is

```
<div id="aaa">
    <p>
        <span>123 main street</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <span>US</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Hope I could help.

Comment: this code is coming from a CMS i don't generate it. I have to work with the output that's handed to me.  I'll try your first example